# Getting Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin when using Django authentication on one url but all origins are allowed

Tags: reactjs, django, authentication, cors

I am running into issues with CORS on Django and React (fetch).

Django is set up like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "rest_framework",
    "corsheaders",
    "users",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
  "http://localhost:3000",
  "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
)
```

The urls in users:

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('login/<str:username>/<str:password>/', login),
  path('logout/', logout),
  path('info/', info),
]
```

and views

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.contrib import auth
from django.http.response import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
@api_view(['GET'])
def login(request, username, password):
  user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
  if user is not None:
    auth.login(request, user)
    return Response('yes')
  else:
    return Response('no')

@api_view(['POST'])
def logout(request):
  auth.logout(request)
  return Response('hmmmmmmm')


@api_view(['GET'])
def info(request):
  if request.user.is_authenticated:
    return HttpResponse('wow, this is really critical information: 5!')
  else:
    return HttpResponse('nothing here...')
```

When I do a request from react

```
  let [message, setMessage] =  useState('waiting...')

  fetch('http://localhost:8000/users/login/Timoty/foo')
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(text => setMessage(text))
```

I get the typical error...
[image: cors error]

What puzzles me the most is the fact that this is a cors issue, I am thinking that maybe I need to do some cookie magic from my react code, but why am I getting cross origin errors then?

It should also be noted that Timoty is registered with password foo in the database, when I try with a user that is not registered in the database, the site works as expected and shows "no". (for example http://localhost:8000/users/login/Bob/foo)

I am aware that it probably is a very bad idea to put the credentials in the url :)

If the issue is with Django's authentication that I am (probably?) using wrong from my react code, the question would be how to do it properly. If not, why is cors getting involved?

Note that the other urls work as expected (no cors issues).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I started using Axios instead of built in fetch, needed to add

```
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

to settings.py, now it works.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS
```

was removed was removed and CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL is now false.